# Centering a scroll view

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

I'm trying to have a ScrollView centered top to bottom within its parent, but I'd also like the ScrollView to be no taller than the height of it's child.    The child's height is variable.  If there is room, the ScrollView should stretch to be exactly the height of it's child.   Any suggestion on how to set up this layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put the ScrollView inside a `android:layout_height="match_parent"` `RelativeLayout`.
2. set the ScrollView to `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`.
3. Set the ScrollView's height to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

This should get you a centered scrollview that is up to but no taller than the relativelayout that contains it.

Out of curiosity, why do you not want the scrollview set to fill_parent/fillViewport? I would suggest doing that, and simply centering the content of the scrollview instead.